# How to properly import function in a ReactJS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I'm having trouble importing a function in react. I used `export default` to export the function. However after importing it I tried to bind it in the render function but I got an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`. Does this mean the function did not correctly import? How do I correctly import it in React?

```
import  onSignUp  from '../../functions/onsignup'
    class ModalExample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

     this.onSignUp=this.onSignUp.bind(this);
    }
    render(){
    return(...)
    }
```

Comment: Please add relevant code as well.

Comment: You used `bind` wrongly. Add your code to get answer.

Comment: Try printing your imported function in a console and if you get undefined your function is not imported or exported properly

Comment: ``this.onSignUp`` where is the definition of this function? It's imported function and not class function to access it as ``this.onSignUp.bind``. You can directly use it like ``this.onSignUp= onSignUp.bind(this)``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra bracket in there, also, the imported function will just be `onSignUp` not `this.onSignUp`.

```
import  onSignUp  from '../../functions/onsignup'

class ModalExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSignUp = onSignUp.bind(this);
  }

  render(){
    return(...)
  }
}
```

You should bind the function in the `ctor` or alternatively assign it in the class to `onSignup` like this:

```
import  onSignUp  from '../../functions/onsignup'

class ModalExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onSignUp = onSignUp.bind(this);

  render(){
    return(...)
  }
}
```

(I think)

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean the function did not correctly import?

Possibly yes.

> How do I correctly import it in React?

import exportedFunction from `'./directorypath';`// if exported using default

import { exportedFunction } from `'./directorypath';` // if default not used while exporting.

A code snippet of the component would give a better picture of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put you declaration in the constructor like this referring to the `onSignUp` you imported instead of `this.onSignUp` that doesn't exists :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSignUp = onSignUp.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the function in the onSignUp file? you might not need to bind it depending on what function it is, however...

this.onSignp = this.onSignUp.bind(this);

Doing this in the constructor will assume you are initializing a new function not the one you are importing, use this instead.

```
this.onSignp = onSignUp.bind(this);
```

And make sure you are properly defining it from where you are declaring

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing a function from out side of React class, then no need to bind it inside React class. You just import and use it. see the below..

**functions/onsignup.js**

function defined and export here.

```
const onSignUp = () =>{
// function code here
}

export default signup;
```

**ModalExample.js**

import the function here and use.

```
import React, {Componenet} from 'react';
import  onSignUp  from '../../functions/onsignup'

class ModalExample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    render(){
      return(
         <button onClick={()=>onSignUp()} />
      )
    }
}
```