# how can we use function of one component into another js file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, chart.js

hello I am new to js I want to ask I have two-component one is the dashboard and another is chart.js I want the dashboard speed date to plot graph on the chart, js luckily I got data from user data and now it's time to send this data to chart.js file I have created two functions in which we get data like this

```
const graphdata =(graph)=>{  
  console.log("initial",graph)
  speedDataGraph(graph)
}
 export const speedDataGraph=(data)=>{
   data;
}
```

now I import this function speedDataGraph=(data)=>{data;} in chart.js and I do console.log(speedDataGraph)it gives undefined here I stuck I don't know how to use this data on chart.js here is the picture below
[image]

Comment: you forgot to add return on your speedDataGraph function and import it like this : import {speedDataGraph} from 'views/Dashboard/Dashboard';

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly import function in a ReactJS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551801/how-to-properly-import-function-in-a-reactjs-file)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to return value in speedDataGraph method that reason you not get value of graph data. so please return data then you can access in char.js file.

I hope you are understand my concept

Comment: still undefined

Answer (score 0):

return value from helper function.

```
export const speedDataGraph=(data)=>{
  return data;
}
```

Also use `{}` braces to import your function as its not default exported function.

```
import {speedDataGraph} from 'views/Dashboard/Dashboard';
```

Comment: i have done this but give undefined i have done like this console.log('chart',speedDataGraph)

Comment: you should pass some data to check it. like this -> console.log('chart',speedDataGraph('some data'));

Comment: in chart.js or dashboard.js

Comment: it says TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: i have updated my question please can you check again

Comment: you can call like this - console.log('chart',speedDataGraph([1,2,3,4,5]));

Comment: console.log('chart',speedDataGraph([1,2,3,4]))
still same

Comment: you might be importing function from wrong path.

Comment: its auto import

Comment: you should modify your question by removing the image, add plain code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235584/discussion-between-amruth-l-s-and-kokab-shakil).